# Split a column at every whitespace

Tags: mysql

Let's say I got word transcriptions (space separated) in one column. Furthermore I got a set of *legal* phones.

How can I split every transcription @ a whitespace to check whether all used  phones are legal ones?

Main question is: how to get a distinct on a column split @ a whitespace?

Let's say the data looks like this:

```
ID | transcriptions
 1 | th i s
 2 | i s 
 3 | s o m e
 4 | t e st
 5 | d a t a
```

Now the output should look like the following:

> th
>   i
>   s
>   o
>   m
>   e
>   t
>   st
>   d
>   a

Comment: Could you please describe using some examples and show expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a8e65f/3/0)):

```
SELECT distinct SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( transcriptions, ' ', l10.n * 10 + l1.n + 1), ' ', -1) AS transcription
FROM data
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UN ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 0
) l1
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 0
) l10
WHERE LENGTH(transcriptions) - LENGTH( REPLACE( transcriptions, ' ', '')) >= l10.n * 10 + l1.n
;
```

Please note that it may not be extremely efficient. You may consider changing your data model and avoid spliting string using SQL.

Each `CROSS JOIN` (l1 and l10) create a number table from 1 to 100 (10*10). If strings are longer that 100, extra `CROSS JOIN` must be added (10*10*10 => 1.000, 10*10*10*10 => 10.000, ...).
The number table is used on characters at each position in the number table and search for spaces.

#### Sample Data:

```
CREATE TABLE data(id int, transcriptions varchar(100));
INSERT INTO data(id, transcriptions) VALUES
    (1, 'th i s')
    , (2, 'i s')
    , (3, 's o m e')
    , (4, 't e st')
    , (5, 'd a t a');
```

#### Output (no specific order):

```
transcription
i
s
o
e
a
m
st
t
th
d
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! Takes some time to compute, but that will be rather some debugging view, so it won't be called that often.

Comment: Yes, this is usually not a job that should done using SQL or only on small datasets...